# Cannot rename indices of multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

There is a multi-index dataframe, with two indices, result_df:

```
print(result_df)
```

returns

```
                                                    a_column  ...        another_column
datetime_end_format datetime_end_format                       ...                      
1                   2023                                1159  ...                  1027
2                   2023                                2765  ...                  2466
3                   2023                                2493  ...                  2303
4                   2023                                3016  ...                  2860
5                   2023                                4174  ...                  4036
6                   2023                                3916  ...                  3870
7                   2023                                 539  ...                   542
```

Both indices are named "datetime_end_format":

```
print(result_df.index)
```

returns

```
MultiIndex([(1, 2023),
        (2, 2023),
        (3, 2023),
        (4, 2023),
        (5, 2023),
        (6, 2023),
        (7, 2023)],
       names=['datetime_end_format', 'datetime_end_format'])
```

It is attempted to rename these:

```
result_df.index.rename(['month','year'])
```

However the index names are unchanged - running print(result_df.index) again shows no change.

What is the error in the code or the approach?

Comment: `result_df.index.names = ['month','year']`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html?highlight=rename#pandas.DataFrame.rename

Comment: `result_df.rename_axis(['month','year'], inplace=True)` or `result_df.index.rename(['month','year'], inplace=True)`